# Escaping double quotation marks in sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

Creating a search and replace function for my application, I am running a test scenario with 3 files, 
array
tscript
test

I am trying to escape double quotation marks but it wont work

script file contains

```
variableName=$1
sed "s#data\-field\=\"${variableName}\.name\"#data\-field\=${variableName}\.name data\-type\=dropdown data\-dropdown\-type\=${variableName}#g" test
```

test file contains

```
data-field=“fee_category.name”
data-field=“tax_type.name”
```

array file contains

```
fee_category
tax_type
```

There is no error code, the output is just what I inputted because the sed command could not find what it was looking for, if I dont use double quotes next to ${VariableName} and remove them from the test file the function works fine.

Comment: Your sample input contains [non-ASCII double quotes](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm), which ASCII `"` i the `sed` command won't match.

Comment: Do you want to search for a literal string or a regexp? If it's a regexp do you want capture groups to be enabled or not? Do you want backreference metacharacters (e.g. `&` or `\1`) to be enabled in the replacement text or not?

Comment: I am searching for the literal string and a replacement for it using regexp

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being clear. If `variableName` has the value `foo.bar` do you want to search for the literal string `foo.bar` or do you want to search for the regexp `foo<any character>bar` so, for example, the former would NOT match `foo8bar` while the latter WOULD match it?

Comment: Double quotes in sed usually does not require escaping. If these chars are not ascii double quotes (hex 022) we need to identify what they are. What is the output of `head -n2 testfile | od -t x1c` ?

Comment: in reference to the non-ASCII double quotes, can you elaborate I dont understand.

Comment: 0000000    64  61  74  61  2d  66  69  65  6c  64  3d  e2  80  9c  66  65
           d   a   t   a   -   f   i   e   l   d   =   “  **  **   f   e
0000020    65  5f  63  61  74  65  67  6f  72  79  2e  6e  61  6d  65  e2
           e   _   c   a   t   e   g   o   r   y   .   n   a   m   e   ”
0000040    80  9d  0a  64  61  74  61  2d  66  69  65  6c  64  3d  e2  80
          **  **  \n   d   a   t   a   -   f   i   e   l   d   =   “  **
0000060    9c  74  61  78  5f  74  79  70  65  2e  6e  61  6d  65  e2  80
          **   t   a   x   _   t   y   p   e   .   n   a   m   e   ”  **

Comment: `“` is different from `"`, the first belongs to the group of non-ASCII double quotes

Comment: YES^ THIS WAS INDEED THE ISSUE, WOW IM BAMBOOZLED BUT THANK YOU SO MUCH HAS BEEN A LONG 2 HOURS!

Comment: @PedroLobito Sorry, but how someone can type `“` ?

Comment: I copy+pasted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment of [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) , i am only writing this answer in order to share some of my findings in case we need a literal match of your special double quotes. It might be useful to other users.

Your quoted text `fee_category.name` has [Unicode Left Double Quotation Mark U+201c](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) quotes on the left side and [Unicode Right Double Quotation Mark U+201d](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) on the right side.

Those non std quotation marks have also some representation in UTF-8 :

[Unicode Left Double Quotation Mark U+201c](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm)
UTF-8 (hex)     0xE2 0x80 0x9C (e2809c)
UTF-16 (hex)    0x201C (201c)

[Unicode Right Double Quotation Mark U+201d](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)
UTF-8 (hex)     0xE2 0x80 0x9D (e2809d)
UTF-16 (hex)    0x201D (201d)

Analyzing your file with `od` utility we can confirm presence of above hex utf-8 sequences in your data:

```
$ echo data-field=“fee_category.name” |od -w40 -t x1c
0000000  64  61  74  61  2d  66  69  65  6c  64  3d  e2  80  9c  66  65  65  5f  63  61  74  65  67  6f  72  79  2e  6e  61  6d  65  e2  80  9d  0a
          d   a   t   a   -   f   i   e   l   d   = 342 200 234   f   e   e   _   c   a   t   e   g   o   r   y   .   n   a   m   e 342 200 235  \n
```

What is interesting is that we can print those unicode characters in bash either by using their unicode code or by using the utf-8 hex series :

```
$ echo -e "\u201c test \u201d"
“ test ”
$ echo -e "\xe2\x80\x9c test \xe2\x80\x9d"
“ test ”
```

Accordingly we can force sed to match those special chars like this:

```
$ string=$(echo -e "\u201c test \u201d");echo "$string"
“ test ”
$ lq=$(echo -ne "\u201c");rq=$(echo -ne "\u201d")
$ sed -E "s/($lq)(.+)($rq)/**\2**/" <<<"$string"
** test **
```

Also this seems to work fine, without the need of using "helper" variables:

```
$ sed -E "s/(\xe2\x80\x9c)(.+)(\xe2\x80\x9d)/**\2**/" <<<"$string"
** test **
```

Meaning that the hex sequence `\xe2\x80\x9c` (or `\xe2\x80\x9d` for right quotes) can be used directly by `sed` to provide a literal match on this special quotes.

You might as well make a pre-process of your files and convert all those non standard quotes to standard quotes using something like :

```
$ sed -E "s/[\xe2\x80\x9c,\xe2\x80\x9d]/\x22/g" <<<"$string"
" test "   #Special quotes replaced with classic ascii quotes.
```

Above test have been done in Debian Testing & Bash 4.4 & GNU Sed 4.4 and may be this techniques will not work in other sed flavors.

Answer (score 0):

In case of doubt, you can try to wildcard them:

```
variableName="fee_category"
sed "s#data-field=.${variableName}\.name.#& data-type=dropdown data-dropdown-type=${variableName}#g" test

# Or, when you do not want those quotes back in your output
sed "s#\(data-field=\).\(${variableName}\)\(\.name\).#\1\2\3 data-type=dropdown data-dropdown-type=\2#g" test
```